# TypeScript exporting and importing

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having a hard time understanding exporting and importing stuff in typescript, how should this one be constructed for example?

src/functions/handle.ts:

```
export default function handle() {
  // do something here.
  console.log("It is handled");
}
```

src/functions/index.ts:

```
import handle from './handle';

export default {
  handle
};
```

src/run.ts:

```
import allFunctions from './functions';

console.log(allFunctions);
```

If I run `node dist/run.js` (I am compiling into `dist`directory) after compiling, I get `undefined`. But if I use

```
import allFunctions from './functions/'
(notice the "/" at the end)
```

it references to an object that includes the exported function.

I also tried using `export * from './handle'` but the result is the same.

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you explain what your goal is? Your intention seems unclear.

Comment: I have objects in run.ts that requires running different functions from functions defined in files from `functions` folder. I am planning to run those like allFunctions[objectInRunTs.property]().

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to achieve is to re-export all your functions from a single file so you just have to import that file to access them all

First of all, you cannot re-export default exports, so you will have to go for named exports. Anyway, avoid default exports, they do not provide much benefits and confuse everyone.

src/functions/handle.ts:

```
export function handle() {
  // do something here.
  console.log("It is handled");
}
```

src/functions/index.ts::

```
export * from './handle';
export * from './anotherFile';
...
```

src/run.ts:

```
import * as allFunctions from './functions/index'
```

Comment: Shouldn't `import * as allFunctions from './functions'` should look into index.ts already?

Comment: good question. I have not tried but I prefer to be explicit than implicit anyway

Comment: This was the problem that's been bothering me. When I add the index it works OK, but when bundled with webpack, it is not necessary, importing from folder works. So it is kind of confusing :)